# Unable to do npm start

Tags: angular8

Can anyone help me the cause or solution of the following error?

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/ng2-tooltip-directive/fesm2015/ng2-tooltip-directive.js 164:194-212
"export 'ɵɵFactoryTarget' (imported as 'i0') was not found in '@angular/core'
ERROR in ./node_modules/ng2-tooltip-directive/fesm2015/ng2-tooltip-directive.js 612:313-331
"export 'ɵɵFactoryTarget' (imported as 'i0') was not found in '@angular/core'
ERROR in ./node_modules/ng2-tooltip-directive/fesm2015/ng2-tooltip-directive.js 753:139-157
"export 'ɵɵFactoryTarget' (imported as 'i0') was not found in '@angular/core'
ERROR in ./node_modules/ng2-tooltip-directive/fesm2015/ng2-tooltip-directive.js 166:0-27
"export 'ɵɵngDeclareClassMetadata' (imported as 'i0') was not found in '@angular/core'
ERROR in ./node_modules/ng2-tooltip-directive/fesm2015/ng2-tooltip-directive.js 614:0-27
"export 'ɵɵngDeclareClassMetadata' (imported as 'i0') was not found in '@angular/core'
ERROR in ./node_modules/ng2-tooltip-directive/fesm2015/ng2-tooltip-directive.js 759:0-27
"export 'ɵɵngDeclareClassMetadata' (imported as 'i0') was not found in '@angular/core'
ERROR in ./node_modules/ng2-tooltip-directive/fesm2015/ng2-tooltip-directive.js 165:24-47
"export 'ɵɵngDeclareComponent' (imported as 'i0') was not found in '@angular/core'
ERROR in ./node_modules/ng2-tooltip-directive/fesm2015/ng2-tooltip-directive.js 613:24-47
"export 'ɵɵngDeclareDirective' (imported as 'i0') was not found in '@angular/core'
ERROR in ./node_modules/ng2-tooltip-directive/fesm2015/ng2-tooltip-directive.js 164:24-45
"export 'ɵɵngDeclareFactory' (imported as 'i0') was not found in '@angular/core'
ERROR in ./node_modules/ng2-tooltip-directive/fesm2015/ng2-tooltip-directive.js 612:24-45
"export 'ɵɵngDeclareFactory' (imported as 'i0') was not found in '@angular/core'
ERROR in ./node_modules/ng2-tooltip-directive/fesm2015/ng2-tooltip-directive.js 753:21-42
"export 'ɵɵngDeclareFactory' (imported as 'i0') was not found in '@angular/core'
ERROR in ./node_modules/ng2-tooltip-directive/fesm2015/ng2-tooltip-directive.js 756:21-43
"export 'ɵɵngDeclareInjector' (imported as 'i0') was not found in '@angular/core'
ERROR in ./node_modules/ng2-tooltip-directive/fesm2015/ng2-tooltip-directive.js 754:21-43
"export 'ɵɵngDeclareNgModule' (imported as 'i0') was not found in '@angular/core'
```

Because of this, I am unable to start my service in Angular 8.

I am using node js 12.22.3, npm version 6.14.3 and

```
Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.803.29
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.803.29
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.803.29
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.803.29
@angular-devkit/core              8.3.29
@angular-devkit/schematics        8.3.29
@angular/cdk                      8.2.3
@angular/cli                      8.3.29
@angular/flex-layout              8.0.0-beta.27
@angular/material                 8.2.3
@ngtools/webpack                  8.3.29
@schematics/angular               8.3.29
@schematics/update                0.803.29
ng-packagr                        5.7.1
rxjs                              6.6.7
typescript                        3.5.3
webpack                           4.46.0
```

Thanks.

Comment: What is your `ng2-tooltip-directive` version?

Comment: I am using version 2.10.3

Comment: Any update on this question. I am facing the same issue ad my angular version is 8.x.x and ng2-tooltip-directive version is 2.10.3

Answer (score 2):

make changes to your package.json. `"ng2-tooltip-directive": "2.10.3"` instead of `"ng2-tooltip-directive": "^2.10.3"`  or `"ng2-tooltip-directive": "~2.10.3"`

Comment: Any reason of using the specific version?